# ffmpeg series of image overlay at specific interval?

Tags: ffmpeg

I am generating series of images for text scrolling, I need to overlay those images on a video at specific interval (for example from 10-15sec), how can we do that using ffmpeg?

Comment: This problem has come up at various times here on SO, e.g., [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/7979585/85950), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9429194/85950), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9423843/85950), [here](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4089214/85950), and so far the only known solution is splitting the movie into pieces, overlaying on the desired pieces and then putting the pieces back together.  Not ideal.

Answer (score 0):

According to FFmpeg developer Stefano Sabatini, this cannot currently be done.

> Right now you can't do that by using the overlay, you need a multi-steps
>   process, where you need to split the file, overlay just in the interested
>   segments and merge again the modified segments, or create an ad-hoc video to
>   overlay which shows the image only in the interested intervals.

[ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2012-January/004062.html](http://ffmpeg.org/pipermail/ffmpeg-user/2012-January/004062.html)